# select min value in B column for same values in A columns excel?

Tags: excel

I would like to get e.g. min or max value from column2 for same value in column1.
In mine example I want max value from column2 for value A (column1) and that is 18, and for B is 27.

I've tried with array function but I cannot manage it to work properly.

Tnx for any tip or solution.

Example:

```
Column1 Column2 Max_value

A       1       18
A       5       18
A       18      18
A       3       18
A       4       18
B       2       27
B       5       27
B       18      27
B       27      27
B       5       27
B       3       27
```

Sorry for poor example, but I couldn't post picture, my rank is not high enough :)

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible without scripting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Find min/max values in a column among those matched from another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904092/excel-find-min-max-values-in-a-column-among-those-matched-from-another-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard "array formula" is like this for C2

`=MAX(IF(A$2:A$100=A2,B$2:B$100))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and copied down column - adjust ranges as required

replace **MAX** with **MIN** to get the minimum values in the next column

Answer (score 2):

This is a cinch with pivot tables. Here's one way to do it.

[image: Excel pivot table]

Comment: Nice coding-free approach!